# Making zsh prompt blink

Tags: zsh, prompt

Is there a way to cause (part of) the zsh prompt to blink? I know that I can set the colours (with %F/%f) and other visual effects (such as %S/%s), but I have not found a format code for turning on blinking.

My ultimate goal is to have part of the prompt to blink if the current status code (`%?`) is non-zero.

My TERM is *xterm-256color*.

Comment: Try the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439482/how-to-make-a-text-blink-in-shell-script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stack Overflow post
[How to make a text blink in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439482/how-to-make-a-text-blink-in-shell-script)
contains several variations on the method for making prompt text to blink.

The variant that worked for the poster is based on
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45634433/165358),
that uses `tput` for issuing the blink-causing sequence:

```
printf '%s%s%s%s' "$(tput setaf 3)" "$(tput blink)" "Title of the Program" "$(tput sgr0)"
```

For other shells, consult the other answers in the linked post.